# jquery calculate value in input function

Tags: jquery, function

I need to jQuery to sum up at #totalpprice append from jQuery. It doesnt seem to work once append/added to oi id="addhereform"

```
    <form method="get" action="here" onsubmit="">
        <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" value="Product Name"/>
        <input type="number" id="pqty" name="pqty" value="3"/>
        <input type="text" id="pprice" name="pprice" value="2.80"/>
        <input type="text" id="totalpprice" name="totalpprice" value="" readonly/>
        <input type="button" id="padd" name="padd" value="add"/>
    </form>

<ol id="addhereform">
<li></li>
</ol>

var sumpprice = $('#pprice').val();
$('#pqty').change(function(){
    var sumpqty = $(this).val();
    var sumtotal = (sumpprice * sumpqty).toFixed(2);
    $('#totalpprice').val( sumtotal );
})
.change();

$('#padd').click(function(){
    var pname = $('#pname').val();
    var pqty = $('#pqty').val();
    var pprice = $('#pprice').val();
    var totalpprice = (pqty * pprice).toFixed(2);
    $('#addhereform li:last').append('<input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" value="' + pname + '"/><input type="number" id="pqty" name="pqty" value="' + pqty + '"/><input type="text" id="pprice" name="pprice" value="' + pprice + '"/><input type="text" id="totalpprice" name="totalpprice" value="' + totalpprice + '"/></li><li>');
});
```

live demo here --> http://jsfiddle.net/koto/cTWCq/

Answer (score 0):

Because you're adding elements dynamically, you need to use `.on()` instead of `.change()` to bind your event handler. You also need to change your logic so that you're locating the sibling cells to perform your calculation...

```
$(document).on('change', '#pqty', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var sumpprice = $this.siblings('#pprice').val();
    var sumpqty = $this.val();
    var sumtotal = (sumpprice * sumpqty).toFixed(2);
    $this.siblings('#totalpprice').val( sumtotal );
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cTWCq/2/

You are also adding duplicate ID's to the page. Consider using unique IDs and use classes in your selectors.

Comment: wow cool thx. I was thinking of adding numbers in. 
so is the sibling is the one that do the work?

Comment: `siblings()` looks for matches in the parent's direct children. In your case it would match elements in the same form or same li.